# Vaadin Liferay Portlet Project using Liferay 6.0.6 and Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, liferay, vaadin, portlet, liferay-ide

I have a question about Vaadin Liferay Portlet. I'm new for this.

I have to use an old Liferay Portal (6.0.6).

I have to develop a new Vaadin portlet in this portal.

I downloaded Eclipse Luna IDE and I installed liferay-plugins-sdk-6.0.6-20110225 and Liferay IDE

I tried to create new Vaadin Liferay Portlet project (New Project -> Vaadin Liferay Portlet) but I obtain this alert message:

> There are no suitable Liferay plugin project available for this new
>   Liferay Vaadin Portlet. Open the new Liferay Plugin Project wizard
>   now?

I tried to select

> YES

option.

I completed all wizard steps.

In one of these steps I can select the type of Portlet:

[image]

I selected Vaadin Portlet and I see this error:

[image]

At the end of this wizard I can see the portlet project folder but there are some issues.
In particular I find these errors:

[image]
[image]

Can't I create a Vaadin Portlet Project using this Liferay Portal version and corresponding Liferay plugins (6.0.6)?

How can I create my Vaadin Liferay Portlet?

Comment: Did you check the following guide? https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Develop+Vaadin+Apps+as+Portlets#section-Develop+Vaadin+Apps+as+Portlets-Using+Liferay+IDE+to+Create+Vaadin+Portlet+Plug-ins

Comment: @luuksen Thx for your comment. What is the difference between to develope the Liferay portlet as suggested in your tutorial or create a Liferay Vaadin Project (as I described in this question)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the exact differences. I developed a liferay vaadin portlet a while ago, but I think I followed the liferay guide and edited portlet.xml myself and deployed it as a war. I see that your example code tries to importe java.awt.Window, was that because you tried to fix the dependencies or did the generator do that for you? Because it should be com.vaadin.ui.Window! I'd recommend to reinstall the necessary plugins and try to follow the guide I posted, maybe it is a little different.